# Netmiko Multiple vendor Backup running-config Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, netmiko

Regarding python and Netmiko
Need help to take running-config backup with multiple devices like  ex:Cisco Aruba and brocade switches with single python script reading  different .csv file  for each vendor. Or CSV file should be present in below format.

I tried to import the CSV format, am I getting error on below code.

```
**device_type        ip                username            password           port**
cisco_ios           192.168.1.2        cisco            C1s??0123$5            22
brocade_fastiron    192.168.1.3        user             B1sc0123$5             22
hp_procurve         192.168.1.4        manager          Hp3s#@#sdsfd           22
```

````
import csv
import os
from datetime import date
import smtplib
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import re
import zipfile
import sys
today = date.today()
target_dir = f"/tftpdata/Region1/{today}"
if not os.path.isdir(target_dir):
    os.makedirs(target_dir)
    print(f"\nCreated {target_dir} folder successfully")
else:
    print(f"\n{target_dir} folder already exists!")
# For Cisco Username and password
usr = "cisco"
pwd = "XXXXXXX"
# For Brocade Username and password
usr1 = "user"
pwd1 = "XXXXXXX"
#For Aruba Username and Password
usr2 = "manager"
pwd2 = "XXXXXXX"
with open(file="iplist.csv", mode="r") as iplist:
    reader = csv.reader(iplist)
    Cisco = [
        {
            "device_type": "cisco_s300",
            "ip": ip.strip(),
            "username": usr,
            "password": pwd,
            "fast_cli": False,
        }
        for ip in iplist
    ]
with open(file="iplist1.csv", mode="r") as iplist:
    reader = csv.reader(iplist)
    Brocade = [
          {
            "device_type": "brocade_fastiron",
            "ip": ip.strip(),
            "username": "usr1",
            "password": "pwd1",
            "secret": "xxxxxxxxx"
            "fast_cli": False,
        }
        for ip in iplist
   ]
with open(file="iplist2.csv", mode="r") as iplist:
    reader = csv.reader(iplist)
    Aruba = [
          {
            "device_type": "hp_procurve",
            "ip": ip.strip(),
            "username": "usr2",
            "password": "pwd2",
            "fast_cli": False,
        }
        for ip in iplist
   ]
DEVICE_LIST = [Cisco, Brocade, Aruba]
for DEVICE in DEVICE_LIST:
    print(f'\n#### Connecting to {DEVICE["ip"]} ####\n')
    with ConnectHandler(**DEVICE) as ssh_conn:
        running_config = ssh_conn.send_command("show running-config")
    with open(
        f'{target_dir}/{DEVICE["ip"]}-running-config-{today}.txt', "w"
    ) as outfile:
        outfile.write(running_config.lstrip())
    print(f'Backup completed for {DEVICE["ip"]}\n')```
````

Comment: In your situation, I use an Excel file with multiple worksheets instead of a CSV for each device type. Try [pandas](pandas.pydata.org)

Comment: Any example .. am new with python .. Help me out sort out these things..

Answer (score 2):

Just create functions to get files info and device config.

Read your CSV/excel file using pandas module or CSV module and iterate over the rows to get the details.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import pandas as pd
```

#Function to get device config

```
def get_device_conf(IP,user,password,device_type):

    devlist = {'device_type': device_type,
       'ip': IP,
       'username': user,
       'password': password,
     }

    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**devlist)
    output = net_connect.send_command("show running-config")
    #"do what you want to do with this output, you can save to file also"
    net_connect.close()
```

#get device details from csv file

```
def get_device_detail(filename):

    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
        device_type=row["device_type"]
        IP=row["IP"]
        username=row["username"]            
        password=row["password"]
    
        get_device_conf(IP,user,password,device_type) #call the get config function to collect config and perform any action
```

#call the get_device_details function to run both of the function and perform the action

```
get_device_detail(filename)
```

#If you have multiple files then simply create a list of filenames and apply for a loop to iterate over all the files.

Example:

```
list_filenames=["file1.csv","file2.csv","file3.csv"]

for filename in list_filenames:
    get_device_detail(filename)
```